# In which field of science that we can prove $0! =1$ and what i can say to studentof high school if he asked about it's prove ??

Tags: education, math-history, convention

In mathematics there are some data , we have took them by convention  and mathematics is

not able to show us them proves , now want just to know  if the "convention" term enough

mathematics condition to say a student if he asked about the prove of $0! =1$ , "should

be for u to take it as convention".

I would like  someone to show me where is the science that proved $0!=1$ while mathematics

not able to prove  $0!=1$ ? is it applied in chemistry field ?

just i want how i can deal with a student in high school if he asked ?

i would interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: It may be explained as saying $x^0 = 1$ for any $x \ne 0$. So, the "empty product" which is $0!$ should be $1$ also. Another explanation, it makes the subsequent formulas (like the binomial coefficients) consistent.

Comment: How about
\begin{align}
3!=3\cdot2!\qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad\frac{3!}{2!}=3\\
2!=2\cdot1!\qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad\frac{2!}{1!}=2\\
1!=1\cdot0!\qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad\frac{1!}{0!}=1\\
\end{align}
From the last step we get $0!=\cfrac{1!}{1}=1$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey The only problem is that it is inconsistent with $\Gamma(0)=(-1)!$

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع: You need to remember that analytic extensions don't have to agree with certain rules that can be deduced on discrete functions. (For example $1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots$ is **NOT** $-\frac1{12}$, but it can be proved to be, if we take these rules and apply them to a particular analytic continuation.)

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila , I forgot that.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع The OP will immediately notice it that it only holds for integer $n\ge0$.

Comment: @PA6OTA , in the fact x^0 is not by convention , there is a prove for it ( just to use exponent law )  , it's seems that you are used just the definition of $n!=n.(n-1)......(n-h+1)$ in $ then u use 0!=1 as it's verified , thanks